# How to manipulate multiple routes values from the JSON response of Google Maps directions services API V3?

Tags: json, google-maps

How to manipulate multiple routes values from the JSON response of Google Maps directions services API V3?

```
directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
        //Need to access the multiple routes values here.
        directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
    }
});
```